# combine var in 2 file with only have match some var python

Tags: python

How to combine two file with only have some match var and print that had match

file1.txt

```
email@email.com b5c2eac4f288490166fe508d77652aea:R7pnHzu94YC81ZYGxtbKyWHzHbF3err0
email@email.com b850c37a676df2cba45a70917be69737:w4YcDLcGb1EP3FMszaChlc1ISJ4WMKmc
email@email.com 34e29d789d455d8b2c0dd2678fbe52cf:k5htfMNJRgQFJ85u9X5Tzw9yoUVZtvpx
```

file2.txt

```
b5c2eac4f288490166fe508d77652aea:R7pnHzu94YC81ZYGxtbKyWHzHbF3err0:123456x
b850c37a676df2cba45a70917be69737:w4YcDLcGb1EP3FMszaChlc1ISJ4WMKmc:12345678x
3bb3c0d55eee3da5a437cba2280a5a51:WZcwgstCh3Ku8pxgx32xtluzHPvupxzb:54321
```

Output

```
email@email.com:123456x
email@email.com:12345678x
```

Try code

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
for line in file1:
   data = line.split(" ")  
   md5  = data[1].strip()
   email = data[0].strip()
for line2 in file2:
        data2 = line.split(":")
        passwd = data2[1].strip()
        if data2[0].strip() == md5:
```

Comment: Are you looking for the differences per line, or within the whole file? That is, can the bit that is the same in both files span multiple lines?

Comment: thanks, im looking for  differences per line.

Comment: Do you know they're in the same order? Or could they be different, and you want to replace each hash with the matching password, wherever it is in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want something like the following.

It consists of three steps:

1. Iterate through the first file, putting the emails in a dictionary, using the MD5 as a key
2. Iterate through the second file, checking whether the MD5 occurs in the dictionary, adding the output line to the `output` list
3. Write the `output` list to the output file, by joining the lines

```py
emails = {}
output = []

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        email, md5 = line.split()
        emails[md5] = email

with open('file2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        md5, passwd = line.strip().rsplit(':', 1)
        if md5 in emails:
            output.append(f'{emails[md5]}:{passwd}\n')

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(output))
```

Note: You only need the `strip()` in the second case (using `rstrip()`) -- to remove any potential leading/trailing whitespace and the newline. Its unnecessary in the first `split()` since `split()` without arguments will handle this for you.

Notice how the `split()` for the first file has no argument -- this is sufficient since the default splitting is done on whitespace.

For the `split()` in the second file, we instead use `rsplit` since we are splitting on `:` and want the first two fields to be combined as one

Comment: Don't forget a `\n` in the line appended. And `f.writelines(output)` would avoid needing the `join`.

Comment: Actually, my laziness in omitting the `strip()`s makes this first point moot. Good point with `writelines` -- I should get used to that instead of `join`ing all the time (bad habit).

Comment: [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with no arguments will remove the newlines, since it splits on all runs of consecutive whitespace and effectively strips the beginning and end. You could do `split(' ')` to keep them.

Comment: thanks, its work ,will print out email that finds password.

Comment: In the first split, its convenient since we don't want those newlines, in the second split (`rsplit`), the trailing newline remains -- which in this case is also convenient since it gives the output line a newline by default (but it would be better to strip the line first e.g. in case of trailing whitespace -- will add that it)

Comment: Ah okay I missed that, my bad.